# Pandas: Automatically generate incremental ID based on pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe, to which various users (name, phone number, address...) are continously being added. Now, I need a function, that automatically generates an ID once a new, non-existing user is added to the dataframe.

The first user should get the ID U000001, the second user the ID U000002 and so on.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: what would be expected for row 1000001?

Comment: **(name, phone number, address...) are continously being added** This is not a good use case for dataframe. DataFrame are designed to load all the data at once. Occasionally you can add/remove rows but not **continuously**.

Comment: @anky don't worry there won't be more than 999,999 rows :)

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for your reply. Why would this not work well with a dataframe? What else would you suggest?

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work. I'm just saying it is not a good design :-). TBH, I don't have any alternatives in mind. I'm not familiar with data stream. On the other note, you can use a dictionary to index the unique ids as you add more. rows.

Comment: QuangHoang makes a valid point though, streaming dataframes do exist but not in pandas. You might have to store the existing dataframe and then append to it.

Comment: @QuangHoang okay I see, it's just for a small use case, so I hope it will work out :) Thanks for suggesting using a dictionary. The one thing I'm not sure about how to do is the creation of the incremental ID based on the previous 'last ID'.

Comment: @anky Yes my goal was to store and append to the existing dataframe anyways! what are you guys referring to when saying 'streaming dataframes'?

Comment: I was referring to spark, not sure if you would need it though with the size of that df: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: The thing is, it wouldn't be problematic if the ID were an int and I'd just add +1 to the previous ID, but due to it being in the format U000001, I'm not sure how to make it work

Comment: @anky thanks! yes, probably not, I don't think the dataframe will have more than 5,000 rows at max tbh

Comment: I am guessing you could try and re-calculate the ids based on *names* after appending - thats one way I can think of without a loopy example in hand? `[*map(lambda x: f"U{str(x).zfill(6)}",pd.factorize(df['name'])[0])]`

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, the main problem is the leading zeros.  i.e. you can't just increment the previous ID, because typecasting '0001' just gives 1 instead of 0001.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Anyways, here's what I came up with.  It's far more verbose than you probably need, but I wanted to make sure my logic was clear.

```
def foo(previous):
    """
    Takes in string of format 'U#####...'
    Returns incremented value in same format.
    Returns None if previous already maxed out (i.e. 'U9999')
    """
    value_str = previous[1:]    # chop off 'U'
    value_int = int(value_str)  # get integer value

    new_int = value_int + 1     # increment

    new_str = str(new_int)      # turn back into string

    # return None if exceeding character limit on ID
    if len(new_str) > len(value_str):
        print("Past limit")
        return(None)

    # add leading zeroes
    while(len(new_str) < len(value_str)):
        new_str = '0' + new_str

    # add 'U' and return
    return('U' + new_str)
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything!  Here's a script you can use to test it:

```
# test
current_id = 'U0001'
while(True):
    current_id = foo(current_id)
    print(current_id)
    if current_id == None:
        break
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! This is exactly what I need and it works perfectly! :)

Comment: No problem! :-)